# Як перекласти «Offshore software R&D» українською?

Tags: переклад, терміни, from-english

> В ен-вікі є стаття https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offshore_software_R&D
>
> В ру-вікі їй відповідає [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Офшорное_программирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%84%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)
>
> В ук-вікі їй відповідає [Офшорна розробка програмного забезпечення в Україні](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%84%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%96)

Питання з [ДОУ](https://dou.ua/forums/topic/19915/) не моє, але воно мене зацiкавило.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Offshore**

В загальному значенні [***офшор***](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%84%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%80) - (дослівно *поза берегом*, *поза межами*) - *офшор*, *той, що вироблений за кордоном*, *закордонний*.

**Software**

Програмне забезпечення.

**R&D (Reasearch & Development)**

*Research* - науково-дослідний.

*Development* - розробка програмного забезпечення.

*R&D center* - центр розробки і наукових досліджень, науково-дослідний центр розробки, рідше науково-дослідний і розробницький центр, розмовний варіант - офшорний R&D центр.

---

Оскільки англійською *Research & Development* мало хто говорить, то і українською переклад зазвичай скорочують. Тому *Offshore software R&D* [перекладають так](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%84%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%96):

- офшорне програмування
- офшорна розробка програмного забезпечення.